# JQuery ui range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

whatever i do i cannot get to this result 
[image: the result i want to have]

using this code

```
<div data-role="rangeslider">
    <input name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="0" type="range">
    <input name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="100" value="100" type="range">
</div>
```

i always get this result 
[image: stupid result i always get]
this should be straight foward right ?
I linked the latest jquery mobile and ui js files and also css files
so what the heck is going wrong ?
i want them to be aligned all next to each other >.<

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: sorry i dont know how to use fiddle :'(

Comment: the code comes from this page 
https://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/
which should work as soon as you link css and js

Comment: thanks for the fiddle question 
i found it was something wrong with linking the js files 
i was linking more than one file at a time on fiddle it worked like a charm
https://jsfiddle.net/yamennassif/zhknp7ks/
so i cleaned my header imported only the files i need 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone comes here with the same problem the solution is to clean your header and to clean your links to css and js files.
i found out i was using an old css link to jquery.mobile

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
```

just add the right css file and make sure to call the latest one which in my case now it is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
```